# how to install a Chrome extension in http://example.com/hello.crx on Opera silently

Tags: google-chrome-extension, opera, opera-extension

Chrome is very restrictive in side loading extensions (not through the Chrome Web Store). I need a way to install an extension for all users of my domain silently. Can Opera do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope I am misunderstanding you, but are you asking how to *secretly install software when a user visits your website*? That's what I assume when you say you want to "install an extension for all users of my domain silently." Or by "silently" do you mean "with only a simple confirmation dialog" rather than "without the user's knowledge"? Do you own the target computers (e.g., all the users are on laptops from your company's IT department)?

Comment: @apsillers I think that "all users of my domain" should be interpreted as Windows Domain. The question is whether Opera supports an analogue of [ExtensionInstallForcelist](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist)

Comment: I agree with @apsillers' concern. Assuming the "silently" is nothing sinister, you should be able to install the CRX file. There is an Opera add-on that allows you to install Chrome extensions in Opera (Blink), but you could've just googled that. What have you tried so far? Have you done any research before asking this question, or encountered any specific problems?

Comment: Sorry I need to clarify. "Domain" in this context is a Google for Work domain. This is an enterprise use case. All users in the domain work for the same business. We have a need to install some common tools all users will use.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google found this: http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-either-stop-users-from-disabling-or-uninstalling-a-Chrome-extension which referenced the following links:

http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist
https://sites.google.com/site/lock5stat/offline-use/installing-for-all-users

Per the Chromium docs you can modify the policies of the OS can force install for all users.